# For getting file listing on a particular directory in Windows, which is the best way AD LDS or custom TCP/IP Client-Server Application

Tags: tcp, active-directory, ldap

I would like to access the file listing on a particular directory in the server. When I googled, I got to know about (Active Directory Light weight Directory Service) AD LDS. It provides many services like domain services, light weight directory services, certification services, federation services etc.

But my requirement is very simple to access the files list on a directory. I can write a simple TCP server and client apps to get the job done. Do I miss anything if I dont opt for AD LDS?